# Python selenium webdriver - driver suddenly "dies" and can't quit, get current_url, open pages

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, urllib2, selenium-webdriver

Sometimes, in the middle of my script, my webdriver instance will just *die*!

And thenceforth, I can't invoke any of its methods.

Some examples:

```
>>> spsel.driver.current_url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 414, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 280, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 321, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1161, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>



>>> spsel.driver.quit()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 55, in quit
    RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 443, in quit
    self.execute(Command.QUIT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 151, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 280, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 321, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1161, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Any ideas why this might be the case?  Any best practice solutions for overcoming?

I'm thinking of occasionally testing for liveness by `driver.current_url` in a try block, and if it throws an exception, then setting the driver to `None`, and then re-instantiating it... but it's an ugly hack and I don't understand why it's needed.

Comment: It would make more sense to see the code of the web server that ought to be checked by this code. "Connection refused" clearly states that there is either no one listening anymore, or there is a rule that stops the listener from getting involved...

Comment: According to the backend engineering department, the web server is fine and doesn't automatically disconnect users.  I think it's a selenium bug?

Comment: what is your selenium version? what browser? Does it happen to all browsers? Are you behind proxy? Is your URL correctly formed?

Comment: I have seen Selenium die for various browser reasons. Can we see the relevant part of your Selenium script?

Comment: I can confirm that it's not the issue of any web server - as *every* address simply doesn't work. Not just that, but simple things that shouldn't be an issue –such as grabbing the current url– throw `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After endless struggles with selenium drivers and FF extensions breaking up. I've removed it completely.

I use http://www.phantomjs.org/ which is headless JS lib. Works like charm.
(and I you want see the page, you can always make screen-shoot )

I mainly work in ruby so: have replace capybara-webkit with poltergeist (which is just a js_driver for capybara)

I'm quite sure there will be similar solution.
Maybe this not answer your question but it will provide with a diffrent look about js testing.

Comment: lol we are having this problem with PhantomJS, but what we did is we just check if the Webdriver isn't responding if it isn't we kill it and start a new one. Works great till now!

Comment: can you detail the steps you did to do this? what process am I looking for

Comment: @SamStoelinga how do you check if a webdriver is not responding?

Comment: I forgot but from memory we just just had some wrapper with a try catch and on exception call the stop method and start to start a new one. Was really simple all python api only

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the selenium webserver running first?

This question suggests that the webserver not running is the problem: [Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198839/selenium-in-python)

```
then the solution is most likely that you need get the selenium server running first.

In the download for SeleniumRC you will find a file called selenium-server.jar (as of a 
few months ago, that file was located at SeleniumRC/selenium-server-1.0.3/selenium-
server.jar).

On Linux, you could run the selenium server in the background with the command

java -jar /path/to/selenium-server.jar 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
```

You will find more complete instructions on how to set up the server here http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#installation

This page has a similar problem: http://johnmudd.infogami.com/blog/5be6

Another similar question: [How do you connect remotely using Python + Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850460/how-do-you-connect-remotely-using-python-webdriver)

Comment: That's not the issue.  I don't need to have the selenium server running since I'm using selenium2 with webdriver.  Having said that, I tried starting up the script having the webserver in the background, and it did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it's a "connection refused" error to your selenium web driver in Firefox which is implemented as an Firefox Extension. The wild guess here is some issue within the extension or Firefox stops the httpd code in the extension from working.

You may attempt to check whether or not you have latest [web driver extension](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#svn/trunk/javascript/firefox-driver) and a compatible Firefox version.

And also you may want to try some alternative browser e.g. Chrome Web Driver (it requires a few lines of change in your python code)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, or at least I think so. On my side the browser (Chrome) would be block and when manually stopping the process in the terminal I would get the same URLError.

At the time I was using Django's LiveServerTestCase as well as Splinter and implementing the following methods:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.browser = Browser()
    super(MyClass, cls).setUpClass()

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.browser.quit()
    super(MyClass, cls).tearDownClass()
```

This would create only one driver for all the tests ran by the class. I also put all my tests into just one method.

Anyway this would lead to the driver blocking at some point.

Then I switched to implementing the Setup and TearDown method an instantiating/quitting the driver in them. This would then create and quit a driver for each test(metho) in the class. I also broke down my tests into several methods.

After that everything would run just fine, while I was doing exactly the same things. So the issue seems to have been mainly doing everything with one driver.

As a tip, you can implement the login stuff into the Setup method as well so that your driver is logged in for every test, this is necessary since quitting the driver also flushes out the session.

this is what the end result looks like:

```
from splinter import Browser
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class MySeleniumTests(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['initial_data.json']

    def setUp(self):
        #fire up your driver
        self.browser = Browser('chrome')
        #login
        self.browser.visit('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, reverse('home')))
        self.assertEquals(self.browser.url, '%s%s' % (self.live_server_url,'/accounts/login/?next=%s' % reverse('home')))
        self.browser.fill_form({'username': 'test', 'password': 'test'})
        self.browser.find_by_tag('button').first.click()
        self.assertEquals(self.browser.url, '%s%s' %  reverse('home')))

    def tearDown(self):
        #quit your driver
        self.browser.quit()
```